# How to call a template ctor of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, constructor, type-deduction

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    template<typename U>
    A() {}

    template<typename U>
    static void f() {}
};

int main()
{
    A<int>::f<int>(); // ok
    auto a = A<int><double>(); // error C2062: type 'double' unexpected
}
```

The issue is self-evident in the code.

My question is:

**How to call a template ctor of a template class?**

Comment: The obvious bypass is `A<int>::A<double>();` but this is illegal syntax. So as Vittorio mentions in his answer, this is impossible without some kind of wrapper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot **directly** call a constructor of a class. If you cannot deduce the constructor's template arguments from the call, then that particular constructor is impossible to invoke.

What you can do is create some sort of *type wrapper* that can be used for zero-overhead deduction:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_wrapper { };

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    template<typename U>
    A(type_wrapper<U>) {}
};

int main()
{
    auto a = A<int>(type_wrapper<double>{});
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gmlTHG5Y4ks4pg5i)

Answer (score 3):

> How to call a template ctor of a template class?

Unfortunately it's impossible; You can't specify template arguments explicitly for constructor templates.

[§17.5.2/5 Member templates [temp.mem]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.mem#5)

(emphasis mine)

> [ Note: Because the explicit template argument list follows the
>   function template name, and because conversion member function
>   templates and **constructor member function templates are called without
>   using a function name, there is no way to provide an explicit template
>   argument list for these function templates.** — end note ]